# Vertical scrollbar is not shown

Tags: html, css

I've inherited a project from a colleague, and I'm facing a very strange behaviour I can't solve.

It's an HTML page that even if it's longer than the screen, it **doesn't show the scrollbar** and it's not possible to scroll at all, even with the mouse wheel.
I've tried to look deeply in the CSS, using the Chrome inspector, but no way to make it scrollable.

I've added at the end of the page a big div, with **red borders**, so it's easier to see the issue.

Here is a live demo: http://mobile.natuplan.com/mobileapp/add-demo.aspx

Edit: I've simplified as much as possible the page to post some code:

```
<h3 class="modal-wnd"><a href="#" onclick="Close();" class="btn-back"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i></a>
    Nuova Richiesta</h3>
<div class="content-wnd modal-wnd">
    <div id="pnlInsert" runat="server">
        <div>
            some content here...<br />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and something else blabla bla<br />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and something else blabla bla<br />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and something else blabla bla<br />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and something else blabla bla<br />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and something else blabla bla<br />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and something else blabla bla<br /><br /><br />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and something else blabla bla<br />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and something else blabla bla<br />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and something else blabla bla<br />
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet and something else blabla bla<br />
        </div>
        <div id="bottom-spacer"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
#bottom-spacer { border: 3px dashed red ;height:550px;}
#pnlInsert{overflow-y:auto;}
.modal-wnd{}
.modal-wnd.content-wnd {
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 10px;
    margin-top: 40px; }
```

Comment: Please post some code here so as to provide a [mcve]. Also: `overflow: scroll;`

Comment: why -1?? too simple? Sometimes also experienced developers can miss the solution that is under their eyes...

Comment: in app.css body overflow:hidden was the reason as already noted. But apart from that you have a big view state and page load is very slow. Maybe you would want to take care of it too (something like 636K for a simple page!).

Comment: @CetinBasoz yes I've seen it! I'm refactoring everything but it's part of a big platform and it's hard to work on it. Thanks btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

remove

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

from `App.min.css` (line 1)

Answer (score 2):

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

in `App.min.css`. Change it to `overflow: auto` for example.

Answer (score 0):

In your css add

```
#bottom-spacer {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

It will add the scrollbar when the content exceeds the height of the div.

```css
#bottom-spacer {
    border: 3px dashed red;
    height: 90px;
    overflow: auto;
}

HERE IS AN EXAMPLE
```

```html
<div id="bottom-spacer">
dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd dkjhasdk kjasd askjd 
</div>
```